# Timestamp not printed on thumbnails with FFMPEG

Tags: video, ffmpeg, timestamp, thumbnails

I have a script using FFMPEG to generate an image with tiled thumbnails every 45 seconds for several videos on a given folder. The images are named with the name of the video it was generated from. It generates the thumbnails for each video but it does not print the time stamps on them. The path to the font file is correct; so I don't know where the issue is. I'm using the script in Fedora Linux.

**Here is the FFMPEG command line code on the script:**

```
 ffmpeg -ss 00:00:05 -i test.mp4 -loglevel 40 -frames 1 -bt 20M -vf "drawtext=fontfile=/usr/share/fonts/open-sans/OpenSans-Light.ttf:timecode='00\\:00\\:00\\:00':r=30:fontcolor=white:x=220:y=220:box=1:boxcolor=black@0.5,select=not(mod(n\,1350)),scale=200:150,tile=15x48" -n "${name}.png"
```

**and this is the console output**

```
ffmpeg version 4.4 Copyright (c) 2000-2021 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 11 (GCC)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --bindir=/usr/bin --datadir=/usr/share/ffmpeg --docdir=/usr/share/doc/ffmpeg --incdir=/usr/include/ffmpeg --libdir=/usr/lib64 --mandir=/usr/share/man --arch=x86_64 --optflags='-O2 -flto=auto -ffat-lto-objects -fexceptions -g -grecord-gcc-switches -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wp,-D_GLIBCXX_ASSERTIONS -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-cc1 -fstack-protector-strong -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-annobin-cc1 -m64 -mtune=generic -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fstack-clash-protection -fcf-protection' --extra-ldflags='-Wl,-z,relro -Wl,--as-needed -Wl,-z,now -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-ld ' --extra-cflags=' -I/usr/include/rav1e' --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-version3 --enable-bzlib --disable-crystalhd --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gcrypt --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libdav1d --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libcdio --enable-libdrm --enable-libjack --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-nvenc --enable-openal --enable-opencl --enable-opengl --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librsvg --enable-librav1e --enable-libsmbclient --enable-version3 --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libsvtav1 --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libv4l2 --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-version3 --enable-vapoursynth --enable-libvpx --enable-vulkan --enable-libglslang --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-libzvbi --enable-lv2 --enable-avfilter --enable-avresample --enable-libmodplug --enable-postproc --enable-pthreads --disable-static --enable-shared --enable-gpl --disable-debug --disable-stripping --shlibdir=/usr/lib64 --enable-lto --enable-libmfx --enable-runtime-cpudetect
  libavutil      56. 70.100 / 56. 70.100
  libavcodec     58.134.100 / 58.134.100
  libavformat    58. 76.100 / 58. 76.100
  libavdevice    58. 13.100 / 58. 13.100
  libavfilter     7.110.100 /  7.110.100
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  9.100 /  5.  9.100
  libswresample   3.  9.100 /  3.  9.100
  libpostproc    55.  9.100 / 55.  9.100
[h264 @ 0x56051b4b3cc0] Reinit context to 1280x720, pix_fmt: yuv420p
[mpegts @ 0x56051b4acc80] max_analyze_duration 5000000 reached at 5000000 microseconds st:0
Input #0, mpegts, from 'test.mp4':
  Duration: 00:04:57.02, start: 1.400000, bitrate: 2853 kb/s
  Program 1 
    Metadata:
      service_name    : Service01
      service_provider: FFmpeg
  Stream #0:0[0x100]: Video: h264 (Main), 1 reference frame ([27][0][0][0] / 0x001B), yuv420p(progressive, left), 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 30 fps, 30 tbr, 90k tbn, 60 tbc
  Stream #0:1[0x101]: Audio: aac (LC) ([15][0][0][0] / 0x000F), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 96 kb/s
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> png (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[h264 @ 0x56051ba69e00] Reinit context to 1280x720, pix_fmt: yuv420p
[Parsed_scale_2 @ 0x56051b5953c0] w:200 h:150 flags:'bicubic' interl:0
[graph 0 input from stream 0:0 @ 0x56051b725ac0] w:1280 h:720 pixfmt:yuv420p tb:1/90000 fr:30/1 sar:1/1
[Parsed_scale_2 @ 0x56051b5953c0] w:1280 h:720 fmt:yuv420p sar:1/1 -> w:200 h:150 fmt:rgb24 sar:4/3 flags:0x4
Output #0, image2, to '.png':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.76.100
  Stream #0:0: Video: png, 1 reference frame, rgb24(pc, progressive, left), 3000x7200 (0x0) [SAR 4:3 DAR 5:9], q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 0.04 fps, 0.04 tbn
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.134.100 png
No more output streams to write to, finishing.00.00 bitrate=N/A speed=   0x    
[AVIOContext @ 0x56051b84c8c0] Statistics: 0 seeks, 2 writeouts
frame=    1 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 Lsize=N/A time=00:00:24.00 bitrate=N/A speed=0.47x    
video:465kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown
Input file #0 (test.mp4):
  Input stream #0:0 (video): 8761 packets read (96159422 bytes); 8760 frames decoded; 
  Input stream #0:1 (audio): 0 packets read (0 bytes); 
  Total: 8761 packets (96159422 bytes) demuxed
Output file #0 (.png):
  Output stream #0:0 (video): 1 frames encoded; 1 packets muxed (476224 bytes); 
  Total: 1 packets (476224 bytes) muxed
[AVIOContext @ 0x56051b4b5d00] Statistics: 107090352 bytes read, 18 seeks
```

Answer (score 0):

The script is working now thanks to llogan. For anyone who wants to use the script, here is the code:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in *{mp4,mkv};
    do name=`echo "$i" | cut -d'.' -f1`
    echo "$name"
   ffmpeg -ss 00:00:05 -i "$i" -loglevel 40 -frames 1 -bt 20M -vf "drawtext=fontfile=/usr/share/fonts/open-sans/OpenSans-Light.ttf:timecode='00\\:00\\:00\\:00':r=30:fontsize=92:fontcolor=white:x=220:y=220:box=1:boxcolor=black@0.5,select=not(mod(n\,1350)),scale=200:150,tile=15x48" -n "${name}.png"

done
```

Comment: You should explain why the code you posted solves your original problem, for the benefit of anyone else who has the same question.

Answer (score 0):

The timecode is probably there, but you did not apply a `fontsize` in drawtext. So it's probably too small to see due to the downscaling. Try:

```
ffmpeg -loglevel 40 -n -ss 00:00:05 -i test.mp4 -vframes 1 -vf "drawtext=fontfile=/usr/share/fonts/open-sans/OpenSans-Light.ttf:timecode='00\\:00\\:00\\:00':r=30:fontcolor=white:fontsize=92:x=220:y=220:box=1:boxcolor=black@0.5,select=not(mod(n\,1350)),scale=200:150,tile=15x48" "${name}.png"
```

Or downscale first, then apply drawtext.

See [drawtext filter documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#drawtext).